# implementing MQTT Mosquitto Client using PHP.. working on terminal..but not in browser

Tags: php, mqtt, mosquitto

M working on MQTT Mosquitto client using PHP. 
First of all installed mosquitto extension to my php
added extension = mosquitto.so  to my php.ini file
restarted apache server

Now what i was facing a problem with mosquitto extension

Run the script on terminal and i found it perfectly working 
But while running on browser i found

Fatal error: Class 'Mosquitto\Client' not found in /var/www/html/sub.php on line 7

Digging out more i wrote a php script to print all extensions and executed it via terminal and browser.. Result was

[image: Image for terminal]

[image: image for browser]

Mosquitto extension is not there for browser but its present for terminal..

Please help.. Thanks a lot in advance..

Comment: `get_include_path()` for both?

Comment: found the same result from terminal and browser for get_include_path() which is .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear

Answer (score 0):

We have two php.ini files in ubuntu "/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini" and "/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
make sure you have extension=mosquitto.so added in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini as well

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm the location of php.ini, using below command :

`php --ini`

result :

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/5.6/cli Loaded
Configuration File: /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini
files in: /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d Additional .ini
files parsed:/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
```

Add extension here
and restart the mosquito & server on pc.... ([Reference](https://github.com/mgdm/Mosquitto-PHP/issues/43))